# Can't add source directory for Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Sorry for the basic question but I can't find an answer that works.

I have VS 2017 Professional 15.6.6

I just want to add source files to Intellisense's database, so that when I e.g. right-click on a symbol and choose "Go To Definition" the appropriate source will open in the editor.

The source in question is in a static .lib that I am linking with my .exe Project.

If I add the source as another Project in the same solution as my .exe project, Intellisense picks it up (whether or not I actually build the Project with the source).  But I would like to just add a directory to what Intellisense sees without changing my Solution.

I tried adding the directory to Project --> Properties --> VC++ Directories --> Source Directories.  That did not work.  What is the purpose of this "Source Directories" setting?

I tried adding the directory to Solution --> Properties --> Debug Source Files.  That also did not work.  What is the purpose of this "Debug Source Files" setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it by adding the source to the solution but disable the project from being compiled. I'm sure there is a better solution for this. I hope that someone else have found it and want to share it with us.

Comment: Thanks, great minds think alike...that's also what I came up with.  It's acceptable but as you say there's got to be something better.  And I'm still not sure what the two settings mentioned in original question are for.  I assume one is to add source files for the debugger to step into when debugging.  But then what about the other one?

Comment: BTW I asked this same exact question here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/279298/cant-add-source-directory-for-intellisense.html.